# Why is $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{\delta^2}\frac{d^2}{dX^2}$ after the substitution $X = \frac{x}{\delta}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I have been working on this for a while and it makes no sense to me. Here's the deal.

We're using the substitution $X = \dfrac{x}{\delta}.$ Then, for some reason, this gives us

$$\begin{split}
X = \dfrac{x}{\delta} & \iff  \dfrac{d}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{\delta} \dfrac{d}{dX} \\
 & \iff \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} = \dfrac{1}{\delta^2} \dfrac{d^2}{dX^2}
\end{split}$$

This makes no sense to me. Why isn't it

$$\begin{split}
X = \dfrac{x}{\delta} & \iff  \dfrac{d}{dX} = \dfrac{1}{\delta} \dfrac{d}{dx} \\
& \iff  \dfrac{d^2}{dX^2} = \dfrac{1}{\delta} \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}.
\end{split}$$

Because I was under the impression that the derivative of $X$ would be $\frac{d}{dX}$ and the derivative of $\dfrac{x}{\delta}$ would be $\dfrac{1}{\delta}\dfrac{d}{dx}$ and that since $\dfrac{1}{\delta}$ is a coefficient, taking the derivative just leaves it there (instead of getting the coefficient $\dfrac{1}{\delta^2}.$

The only thing that anyone every says to me is that it's the chain rule. Which doesn't make sense to me because I thought the chain rule was

$$\left(\begin{array}{c} \text{derivative of} \\ \text{the outside} \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} \text{derivative of} \\ \text{the inside} \end{array} \right)$$

If that's the case, what is the outside function and what is the inside function?

NOTE: If anyone wants any more context than what I gave, we are using these to solve second order linear differential equations, specifically as it applies to boundary layers. If you want more info than this, I'd be happy to provide some.

Comment: I recommend picking a favorite function - say, $f(x)=\sin x$ - and differentiating twice with respect to $x$, then writing the function in terms of $X$ and differentiating twice with respect to $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this actually means is that $X(x) = \frac x\delta$ is to be composed with a function in $x, g(x)$ such that we obtain a function in $X, f(X)$, hence.

$$f(X(x)) = f(\frac x\delta)$$
and
$$\frac {d^2}{dx^2} f(X(x)) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} f(\frac x\delta) = \frac d{dx} \Big( f'(\frac x\delta) \cdot \underbrace{\frac d{dx} X(x)}_{=\frac1\delta} \Big) \\
= \frac1\delta \frac d{dx} f'(\frac x\delta) = \frac1\delta f''(\frac x\delta) \cdot \underbrace{\frac d{dx} X(x)}_{=\frac1\delta} = \frac1{\delta^2} f''(\frac x\delta) = \frac1{\delta^2} f''(X)$$
Where $f'' = \frac {d^2}{dX^2} f$, so we can say that
$$\frac {d^2}{dx^2} = \frac1{\delta^2} \frac{d^2}{dX^2}$$
This is all a bit unclean because you think of $\frac d{dX}$ as a function where it is in fact an *operator* (It *operates* on functions).

Comment: How, then, are you getting $\dfrac{1}{\delta^2}$ out of the deal?

Comment: @BarkJr. Has the application of the chain rule become clearer now?

Comment: Yes it has. Thank you for that thorough edit.

Comment: @BarkJr. Happy to help :) If anything remained unclear, do not hesitate to ask!